# Insertion and update validation

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a case where the operator had to change things manually through management studio.
and a Exception thrown on the app level due to operator mistake.

I want to use trigger or Check constraint on the input.

I wonder about the performance drawbacks, remember that it can be balk insertion.

Is it a common practice to not check at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, forget about performance until you know it's a real problem. Instead, concentrate on building a simple, robust application that works correctly and keeps your data consistent. Both triggers and CHECK constraints are very commonly used ways of ensuring data integrity, so there is no fundamental problem with using them.

If bulk inserts are a concern, then you can disable constraints and/or triggers during the bulk load, and most of the standard tools have support for that e.g. by default, the BULK INSERT command and the bcp.exe utility don't fire INSERT triggers and ignore CHECK and FOREIGN KEY constraints.